# Is it possible that given any random variable, we can find a bijective function such that transform Gaussian r.v. into target random variable?

Tags: probability

Consider the change of variable theorem

a bijective function $f(X) = Y$ where $X \sim N(0,I)$.

Assume that $X,Y$ are random variable distribution continuous over Euclidean space.

$$p(Y) = p(f^{-1}(Y))|\text{(det}\frac{\partial f^{-1}(Y)}{\partial Y})|$$

I'm interesting to know that

(1) if given any $Y \sim $ any distribution. Can we design a bijective function (where its inverse and forward can be analytically computed) that transform $X \to Y$

(2) If (1) is possible, is it possible that $f$ is also volume preserved ? (That is the determinant of the Jacobean part is 1) ?

Comment: Ceratainly not possible if the given distribution corresponds to a random variable taking only finite number of values.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Sorry; I didn't make it clear; we should have assume that both $X,Y$ are random variable of distribution continuous over Euclidean space

Comment: If $Y$ is unknown, how can you do anything?  But if $Y$ is a continuous random variable with cumulative distribution function $F(y)$ then $F^{-1}(\Phi(X))$ will have the distribution of $Y$ while $\Phi^{-1}(F(Y))$ will have the distribution of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Phi$ be the CDF of the standard normal distribution, and $F$ be the CDF of $Y$, we can transform $Y$ to a Gaussian random variable $z$ by $z = \Phi^{−1}(F(y))$. The function $\Phi^{−1} \circ F$ is invertible under some mild assumptions.

If we require $\Phi^{−1} \circ F$ to be volume-preserving, then $\Phi=F$ and this implies $Y=\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.